# Evaluate $ f(a) = \int^a_{-a}|x|dx$ of $a=2$

Tags: integration

I want to evaluate this integral $$ f(a) = \int^a_{-a}|x|dx$$between $a$ and $-a$ and I know that  $\int^a_{-a}|x|dx$ is divided into two: $$\int^a_{-a}|x|dx \rightarrow a>0 = \int^a_{0}xdx  $$
$$\int^a_{-a}|x|dx \rightarrow a<0 = \int^0_{-a}-xdx  $$

after I evaluate it I get zero, so I dont know if I`m right.

What I did is : 
$$a<0 \rightarrow \int^0_{-2}-xdx = \frac{-x^2}{2}|^{0}_{-2} = -2 $$
$$a>0 \rightarrow \int^2_{0}xdx = \frac{x^2}{2}|^{2}_{0} = 2 $$
Thanks!

Comment: check again this:$$\frac{-x^2}{2}|^{0}_{-2} = -2$$

Comment: Ah I see it now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the sign of the first integral wrong:
$$\int^0_{-2}-xdx = \frac{-x^2}{2}|^{0}_{-2} = 0 - \frac{-(-2)^2}{2}=2$$

Answer (score 0):

When you have an even function $g$, that is $g(-x)=g(x)$ for all $x$, you can always do
$$
f(a)=\int_{-a}^a g(x)\,dx=
\int_{-a}^0 g(x)\,dx+
\int_{0}^a g(x)\,dx
$$
and do the substitution $x=-t$ in the first integral, getting
$$
f(a)=-\int_{a}^0 g(-t)\,dt+\int_{0}^a g(x)\,dx=
\int_{0}^a g(t)\,dt+\int_{0}^a g(x)\,dx=
2\int_{0}^a g(x)\,dx
$$

Answer (score 0):

It's best to consider this problem geometrically, it's far more simple.

$$\int_{-a}^{a} |x|dx = a^2$$

because it's just the area under the curve $f(x) = |x|$ which is "two triangles with base and height $a$".

Thus it's just $$2*\frac{1}{2}\text{(base)}\text{(height)}=2*\frac{1}{2}*a*a$$

Since $a=2$, the answer is 4.

Algebraically speaking, the reason why your answer did not work is because

$$|x| = \begin{cases} & -x \quad (x<0) \\
&x \quad \quad (x\ge0)\end{cases}$$

So the $-2$ you got should have been a $+2$.